# Extract the string in a struct of arrays

Tags: matlab

I have a struct of arrays.

```
ci = tdfread(pathToData, delimiter)
```

`disp(ci)` give this

```
                 time: [11513x19 char]
                  bid: [11513x1 double]
            bid_depth: [11513x1 double]
      bid_depth_total: [11513x1 double]
                offer: [11513x1 double]
          offer_depth: [11513x1 double]
    offer_depth_total: [11513x1 double]
```

I can loop through the structure of arrays for the doubles fine, but time code below `ci.time(row)` just returns the first character of the string not the whole  string. How do I get the whole string per row?

```
foundOpen = false;
row = 1;
while(false == foundOpen)
   t = ci.time(row)
   Bid = ci.bid(row)
   Ask = ci.offer(row)
   dt = datetime(t)
   h = hour(dt)
   if h > 12
       foundOpen = true;
   end

   row = row + 1;
end
```

Comment: In MATLAB, passing a single subscript to an array is called [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511). For vectors the behavior is as expected since they only have one dimension. However, unlike the rest of your variables, `time` is a 2d array and not a vector, so in each iteration of your loop you are addressing a single value rather than the row. See MATLAB's [matrix indexing documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85544). You want the [`:` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [colon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator:

```
ci.time(row, :)
```